# Mysql join columns from multiple dynamic tables

Tags: mysql

I wanted to ask wether that's possible with one mysql query or not.
Image, I have table 'users', which holds a general information about the users. And then there is a table 'zodiacs' which holds info about all the zodiacs (zodiac name, birth period start and birth period end).

Can I get users zodiac together with the query where I ask for the user? What I was thinking could look something like this:

```
    SELECT users.*, zodiacs.name AS zodiac
    FROM users,zodiacs
    WHERE zodiacs.period_start <= users.birthdate 
    AND zodiacs.period_end > users.birthdate
    AND zodiacs.calendar = 'chineese'
```

Don't look for a zodiac logic, I don't know if the zodiacs differ for other cultures or not. But the main idea is that the zodiacs table could have more items fro the period mentioned but for different calendars.

So, is it possible to query like this?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to use the `JOINS` in your table. Try to use a JOIN based on certain column of your table `users` and `zodiacs`

Something like this:-

```
SELECT users.*, zodiacs.name AS zodiac
FROM users INNER JOIN zodiacs ON users.id=zodiacs.id
WHERE zodiacs.period_start <= users.birthdate 
AND zodiacs.period_end > users.birthdate
AND zodiacs.calendar = 'chineese'
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does users.id=zodiacs.id mean? I'm asking, because user id is not the same as zodiac id

Comment: I have just taken that as an example. In your table you must have some id or other column through which you can join the two tables. Hope that makes it clear!!!!

Comment: In your users and zodiac table you may have a different column name. I have just taken **id** to tell you how you have to join the two table.

Comment: But i think there is nothing in common between user and the zodiac. Only that the users zodiac is determined by users birthdate. Can you think of something that would work for this example?

Comment: Rahul, why did you disapear?